Closing Workbook Opened via Hyperlink
Not sure what I am doing wrong.  The code works up until I want to close the workbook (from hyperlink) after pulling the data I need before going to the next hyperlink in the column and repeating the same process (same information, same cell data).  I have this code in a separate module before incorporating it into the main code which is below it.
Sub OpenHyperlinkAndCopyData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As range
    Dim hyperlinkAddress As String
    Dim dataToCopy As Variant
    Dim hla As Object
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each cell In ws.range("B12:B208")
        If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            hyperlinkAddress = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
            Workbooks.Open hyperlinkAddress
            
            End If
            With hla
            dataToCopy = Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").range("C4").Value
            cell. Offset(0, 2).Value = dataToCopy
            Workbooks(hyperlinkAddress).Close savechanges:=False
        End With
      
    Next cell

End Sub

Sub VBA_Loop_Through_all_Files_in_subfolders_Using_FSO_Early_Binding()
    
    'use const for fixed values
    Const FLDR As String = "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance"
    Const LIST_START_ADDR As String = "B12"
    
    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject, oFolder As Object, c As range
    Dim oSFolderFile As Object, sFile As Object, sfolder As Object
    
    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FLDR)
    
    Set c = Sheet1.range(LIST_START_ADDR) 'start here
    
    For Each sfolder In oFolder.SubFolders     'loop through subfolders
        For Each sFile In sfolder.Files        'loop all files in each subfolder
            If sFile.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then   'do we want to list this file?
                c.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=sFile.Path, _
                               TextToDisplay:=oFSO.GetBaseName(sFile.Name)
                Set c = c.Offset(1)            'next cell down
            End If 'is .xlsm file
        Next sFile
    Next sfolder
            
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim tmpArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim range As range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        
        lastRow = .range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If InStr(1, .range("B" & i).Value, " ") Then
                tmpArray = Split(.range("B" & i).Value, " ")
                .range("B" & i).Value = tmpArray(0)
                .range("C" & i).Value = tmpArray(1)
            End If
        Next i
    
    End With
    
End Sub


When you want to access a Workbook from the Workbooks.Collection by name, you need to specify the name without path. It doesn't matter that the workbook was opened using the Hyperlink address. So when the Excel file in the Hyperlink is "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance\book1.xlsm", you need to use Workbooks("book1.xlsm").
A much better solution is to assign the opened workbook to a variable. Is looks as if you already defined the variable hla for that because you are using With hla, but you don't assign anything to it so it stays Nothing.
Btw: The part that copies data needs to be put into the If-branch, else you would try to copy data even if you didn't open a new workbook.
Have a look to the following code. Note that there is a dot before .Sheets and .Close, it tells VBA that you want to use the object of the With-clause (hla):
For Each cell In ws.Range("B12:B208")
    Dim hla As Workbook
    If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        hyperlinkAddress = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        Set hla = Workbooks.Open(hyperlinkAddress)
        With hla
            dataToCopy = .Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").Range("C4").Value
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = dataToCopy
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
    End If
Next cell


Retrieve Data from Closed Workbook

Not tested!

A Quick Fix

Qualify your objects (workbook, worksheet, range...)!

Sub OpenHyperlinkAndCopyData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim hyperlinkAddress As String
    Dim dataToCopy As Variant
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range("B12:B208").Cells
        If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            hyperlinkAddress = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
            With Workbooks.Open(hyperlinkAddress)
                dataToCopy = .Sheets("ATTENDANCE RECORD").Range("C4").Value
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = dataToCopy
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub

At Once
Sub RetrieveAttendanceRecords()
    
    ' Define constants.
    ' Source
    Const SRC_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH As String = _
        "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Attendance"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "ATTENDANCE RECORD"
    Const SRC_COPY_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "C4"
    Const SRC_REQUIRED_FILE_EXTENSION As String = "xlsm"
    ' Destination
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FIRST_HYPERLINK_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B12"
    Const DST_SPLIT_COLUMN As String = "C"
    Const DST_PASTE_COLUMN As String = "D"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference the destination objects.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_HYPERLINK_CELL_ADDRESS) 'start here
    ' Clear existing data.
    With dcell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dcell.Row + 1)
        .Clear
        .EntireRow.Columns(DST_SPLIT_COLUMN).Clear
        .EntireRow.Columns(DST_PASTE_COLUMN).Clear
    End With
    
    ' Reference the FileSystemObject object and the root folder.
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject:
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fsoFolder As Scripting.Folder:
    Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(SRC_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim fsoSubfolder As Folder, fsoFile As File, SplitName() As String
    Dim sFilePath As String, sBaseName As String, sFileExtension As String
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, scell As Range
    
    ' Loop through the subfolders of the root folder and do your thing.
    For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
        For Each fsoFile In fsoSubfolder.Files
            ' Check the file extension.
            sFilePath = fsoFile.Path
            sFileExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(sFilePath)
            If StrComp(sFileExtension, SRC_REQUIRED_FILE_EXTENSION, _
                    vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' has required file extension
                
                ' Add hyperlink.
                sBaseName = fso.GetBaseName(sFilePath)
                dcell.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                    Anchor:=dcell, _
                    Address:=sFilePath, _
                    TextToDisplay:=sBaseName
                
                ' Split the source base name (hyperlink text) into 2 columns!?
                If InStr(sBaseName, " ") > 0 Then ' contains
                    SplitName = Split(sBaseName, " ")
                    dcell.Value = SplitName(0)
                    dcell.EntireRow.Columns(DST_SPLIT_COLUMN).Value _
                        = SplitName(1)
                'Else ' has no space ' do nothing
                End If
                
                ' Retrieve value from source workbook.
                Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
                Set sws = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                    Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not sws Is Nothing Then ' sheet exists
                    Set scell = sws.Range(SRC_COPY_CELL_ADDRESS)
                    dcell.EntireRow.Columns(DST_PASTE_COLUMN).Value _
                        = scell.Value
                'Else ' sheet doesn't exist; do nothing
                End If
                swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just read (copied) from

                Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1) ' next cell (row)
            
            'Else  ' has wrong file extension; do nothing
            End If
        Next fsoFile
    Next fsoSubfolder
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    'dwb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Attendance records retrieved.", vbInformation
     
End Sub

